# type error and short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: javascript, typescript

TS Code

```
image = this.selectedItem.image.url || null;
```

The Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null
```

My question is, why isn't the || null kicking in instead of it throwing a type error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortest option you have is:

```
image = this.selectedItem && this.selectedItem.image && this.selectedItem.image.url || null;
```

If any of the `&&` fails, you'll get `null` instead, but you have to check every "level" of the object you're trying to access.

This works because the `&&` takes priority over `||` for order of operation. The above statement is similar to:

```
x = (((a.b) && (a.b.c)) && (a.b.c.url)) || null;
```

What you had, on the other hand, was similar to:

```
x = (a.b.c.url) || null;
```

You can't get `url` if `a.b` does not have a property `c`. That's what the error was thrown on, and that's not something the "or" at the end can catch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about what ["short-circuit"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) means.  Boolean operators are evaluated from left to right (`&&` before `||` but left-to-right otherwise) until the result is either definitely falsy or truthy, and then it stops without evaluating anything else.  In your case, the error occurs while `this.selectedItem.image.url` is being evaluated, and the `||` operator is never reached.

JavaScript lacks a [null/undefined-coalescing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator) operator such as the [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) "`?.`", which would let you do something like `this.selectedItem?.image?.url` to prevent dereferencing `undefined` values.

Instead, you need to check each possible nested property for existence, if it is possible for them to be undefined:

```
image = (this.selectedItem && this.selectedItem.image && this.selectedItem.image.url) || null;
```

(I'm sure other answers have mentioned something like this... ah, yes, @Cerbrus has it)  *This* is now short-circuiting in a way that helps you.  As soon as one of those items is falsy, the whole parenthesized term evaluates as falsy without throwing an error.  Then you get falsy-`|| null` which becomes `null`, as you want.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `this.selectedItem.image.url`, but for that to be possible, you need to make sure that `this.selectedItem` and `this.selectedItem.image` exist first.

You could try the following:

```
image = this.selectedItem && this.selectedItem.image ? this.selectedItem.image.url || null : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check also if the field `image` exists I think. Try to use ternary operator instead:

```
image = this.selectedItem.image ? this.selectedItem.image.url : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the error occurred when `this.selectedItem.image.url` itself was evaluated.  You can fix it this way:

```
this.selectedItem.image = this.selectedItem.image || {}
image = this.selectedItem.image.url || null;
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript:

```
image = this?.selectedItem?.image?.url || null;
```

Comment: This is a syntactically elegant solution to the problem, but does not directly answer the OP's question, which was why the short-circuit evaluation didn't treat the error as falsey and evaluate the other side of the `||`